# Error while publishing web application on iis 7 using visual studio 2012 and windows 8

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting below error while publishing site on iis 7.I am using visual studio 2012 and windows 8.

**Web deployment task failed (There was an error reading iis configuration schema from C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\schema)**

I don't want to make it as my default web site i want to publish it on any port other than 80 .
I am running visual studio in administrator mode too.I have all permissions on iis. Still getting the error.

Is it necessary to create virtual directory and check ***use local iis web server*** option and all those settings in "Web" option of project properties while publishing?

Which settings i have to do to get rid of this error ? Help Me.

Comment: This seems to be a known issue but for VS 2010. refer this link. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2735834. Have you tried the work arounds given there?

Comment: Did you try Googling for the error message? :-D Found this on SuperUser when I did http://superuser.com/questions/791085/there-was-an-error-reading-iis-configuration-schema-from-c-windows-system32-i